# No data return after ajax submit

Tags: jquery, json, post

Anyone for telling me why my following code do not returns me an array with all my values ?

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(getDatas()).done(function(r_getDatas){
        var json = $.parseJSON(r_getDatas);
    });

    function getDatas() {
        return $.post("assets/php/ajax/myscript.php", {
            updateType: this.id,
            data: $('#'+this.id).serialize()
        }, "json");
    }           
});
```

In my PHP, I have:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

And my form is the following:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="user-first-name" />
    <input type="text" id="user-last-name" />
    <input type="email" id="user-email-address" />
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

I do not want another structure to solve the problem, I just want to understand my problem first.

Comment: `print_r()` doesn't output JSON.

Comment: As @Juhana pointed out, you'll need to use `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: if you have `'json'` -> `$.post({...},'json');` you don't need `$.parseJSON()` -> `var json = $.parseJSON(r_getDatas);`, use 1 or the other.

Comment: My alert is now : `{"data":""}`. Any reason why it's empty?

Comment: `#myForm` != `id="user-tab-infos"` -> `$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {` && `<form id="user-tab-infos">`

Comment: By elimination, the problem comes from this line : `$('#'+this.id).serialize()`.

Comment: @Sean : copy paste error. I changed it. But the same. See my comment before.

Comment: Try adding `this` to your function -> `function getDatas(this) {` and `$(getDatas(this)).done(function(r_getDatas){`

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is inside getDatas(). You will have to pass an argument into that function and quite honestly I don't know why you create it in the first place